# How can I print type attributes in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, ada

Is there a way to print a type attribute from inside GDB? 
E.g. Integer'Size.

Comment: Do you think typing "print sizeof(int)" on the gdb commandline solves your problem?

Comment: The question is tagged with ada, so I interpret this type attribute to be some to me unknown ada specific thing, and I do not think sizeof is the answer.

Comment: sizeof() is C/C++... the question is definitely Ada specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

(gdb) p *thing'attribute*

Some attributes are recognized, and others aren't. (In what's listed below, Found is a Boolean variable.)

```
gdb) p integer'size
Attempt to use a type name as an expression
(gdb) p found'size
$2 = 8
(gdb) p integer'first
$3 = -2147483648
(gdb) p integer'last
$4 = 2147483647
```

Here's the list from the [Ada section](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Omissions-from-Ada.html#Omissions-from-Ada) of Debugging with gdb:

```
Only a subset of the attributes are supported:
 
     * 'First, 'Last, and 'Length on array objects (not on types and subtypes).
     * 'Min and 'Max.
     * 'Pos and 'Val.
     * 'Tag.
     * 'Range on array objects (not subtypes), but only as the right operand of the membership (in) operator.
     * 'Access, 'Unchecked_Access, and 'Unrestricted_Access (a GNAT extension).
     * 'Address.
```

(Hmm, that list may be dated, since I could do Integer'Last, despite the first bullet saying that it's not valid on types.)